# How to rebuild a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

> This code below is now working. Credit to Matt-SL who pointed out the
>   difference between substr and substring

This function serve to add tags to the text in a `textarea` just like the one you use to put your text in  bold in your question&answer on Stackoverflow.

```js
var lastFocus;

$("#bold").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    befString = "<b>";
    aftString = "</b>";
    dif = aftString.length - befString.length;

    if (lastFocus) {
        setTimeout(function () { lastFocus.focus() }, 10);
        var textEdit = document.getElementById('textEdit');
        var befSel = textEdit.value.substr(0, textEdit.selectionStart);
        var aftSel = textEdit.value.substr(textEdit.selectionEnd, textEdit.length);
        var select = textEdit.value.substr(textEdit.selectionStart, textEdit.selectionEnd-aftString.length );
        textEdit.value = befSel + befString + select + aftString + aftSel;
    }
    return (false);
});
    

$("#textEdit").blur(function() {
    lastFocus = this;
  
});
```

```css
#textEdit{
width:300px;
height:200px;  
}

#bold{
font-size:25px;
cursor:pointer;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editToolBar" class="editToolBar">
  Select all 2's and
<span id="bold"></b>click here</b></span>
</div>
<textarea id="textEdit" type="text" name="textEdit" size="" class="editDocInput" data-type="" >111112222233333</textarea>
```

**My problem:**

I can't figure out why the string is not being put back together properly. Try it and see for you self.

Comment: I get `11111<b>222223</b>33333` - what are you expecting?

Comment: humm im expecting 11111  222222 333333 cuse i have only selected the 2's

Comment: I assume you stepped through this code line by line to see what it was doing? What did you see?

Comment: Well i was using substr on select when it should have been substring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line in which you define `var select` to use `substring()` instead of `substr()`, and no longer subtract `aftString.length` from `textEdit.selectionEnd`. This means the text selection indices line up with the expected parameters of the `substring()` function.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vq4c6mrq/)  to demonstrate.

```
var select = textEdit.value.substring(textEdit.selectionStart, textEdit.selectionEnd);
```

As per [the documentation for selectionEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectionEnd), it is the index of the first character **after** the selection.

The difference between [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) is what they expect as their second parameter:

- `substr(startIndex, length)`
- `substring(startIndex, endIndex)`

Comment: Wright cause substr will count and substring is giving position. Thank you that worked perfect now You got your self an answer!